# Creating loop that copies certain cells given specific cell values

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Hi I have tired creating a loop which copies the entire row and pastes it in another worksheet, dependent upon two things.

Firstly, there is a level of completion column, if the values are not equal to 100% then they should be copied, also I only want rows copied that are not blank.

Having copied the rows into the next sheet, I want to run through column B and each time the value changes there should be inserted a new blank row.

I am not sure whether you can use this kind of loop this way, any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sheets("Tracker").Activate
    For Each c In Range("H:B")
        If c.Value <> "100%" _
        And c.Offset(0, -6) <> "" Then
            EntireRow.Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
            Selection.Copy
        End If
    Next
Sheets("Project Overview").Activate
    Range("A24").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


Sheets("Project Overview").Activate
    For Each b In Range("B24:B")
        If b.Value <> "" Then
           Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: A screen of your excel could be help.

Comment: can you elaborate on ` each time the value changes ` How do you know it changes? Your code just has if it's not blank you want to insert a row under the row? Does not being blank signify a **change**?

Answer (score 0):

First, the line `For Each c In Range("H:B")` will loop through every cell in columns B-H. Is this really what you want? I don't think so. It will take your code forever to loop through that! It will also check your conditions for each and every cell!

Try the code I have pasted below. It uses `AutoFilter` which is much faster and more reliable, along with the `SpecialCells`, method to copy and paste the data.

When you insert the rows, you need to step backward from the last row to the beginning. This is because when Excel insert rows it will through your original counter off.

```
Sub FilterCopy()

Dim wT As Worksheet, wPO As Worksheet

Set wT = Sheets("Tracker")
Set wPO = Sheets("Project Overview")

With wT

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("B1:H" & lRow)
        .AutoFilter 7, "<>100%" '7th column not 100% (column H)
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>" '1st column not blank (column B)
    End With

    Intersect(.UsedRange,.UsedRange.Offset(1), .Range("B1").EntireColumn).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy

End With

With wPO

    .Range("A24").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    lRow = .Range(.Range("B24"), .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Rows

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = lRow To 24 Step -1

        If .Range("B" & i) <> "" Then .Range("B" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the help much appreciated. I am currently getting a Run-time error, stating that the Application-defined or object-defined error. It relates to the following line -  Intersect(.UsedRange.Offset(1), .Range("B1").EntireColumn).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy - I am not really familiar with this so I don't really know where to start to try and resolve the problem.

Comment: I just looked at I had misspelled `Intersect` as `Interset`. That may be the error. I also added the `.UsedRange` property as well so you don't get an extra line. To explain this, `Intersect` is a method that will choose a range at the intersection of whatever range arguments you add. So in this case, I intersect the entire used range (where data exists), offset it by 1 row (assumes first row is headers) and then entire column B. From there, the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` method only chooses the visible cells (the rows that are filtered). See if the fix I made helps.